# Fastest way to send 500 requests using JS

Tags: javascript, fetch, httprequest

I need to write a function that fetches the rate limit test page 500 times with a 200 status code as fast as possible. Cloudflare will rate limit you if you make more than 10 requests within a minute to https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test.

This is my code so far:

```
const getRateLimited = () => {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    promises.push(fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test'));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(promise => res.send(promise[0].status))
};
```

Is there a better way of doing this and using `setTimeOut`?

Comment: "as fast as possible" would be with a 6 second wait between requests - oh, wait, you want to TEST the rate limit - then what you're doing will do that and that is about as fast as you can go - what is the issue?

Comment: The objective of this question is not clear. Do you want to get rate-limited or you want 500 successful requests as fast as possible without getting rate-limited?

Comment: That's how the question was presented. Re-reading the comments and the question makes me believe 500 successful requests. How can I add a `setTimeOut` properly to this code?

Comment: lol, how are you gonna know how long and when to wait before you get rate-limited? I'm assuming you only want the code to work for this specific webpage, correct?

Comment: Yes - it is only for that page. Also, if you click the link, "If you refresh your browser 10 times in one minute on this page, your IP will be rate-limited for a minute."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 requests per minute is 1 every 6 seconds

So, just wait between requests

Here is code using async/await - no error checking, that's up to you

```
const getRateLimited = async () => {
    const responses = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test');
        responses.push(response);
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 6000));
    }
    return res.send(responses[0].status); // why?
};
```

Why do you `res.send` the first status though?

---

edit: thinking about it, you want as fast as possible,

First, make the request start every 6 seconds, and remove the last delay

```
const getRateLimited = async () => {
    const responses = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        const now = Date.now();
        const response = await fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test');
        responses.push(response);
        if (i < 499) {
            const after = Date.now();
            const delay = 6000 - (after - now);
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
        }
    }
    return res.send(responses[0].status);
};
```

This should make 500 requests over 2994 seconds - which is as fast as you can go I believe

---

edit: of course, if you can make 10 requests, then wait a minute, then make 10 requests, then wait a minute ... rinse and repeat ... you can do it in 2940 + some seconds for the last 10 requests - that would knock another 50-54 seconds off the time it takes

```
const getRateLimited = async () => {
    const responses = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test/');
        responses.push(response);
        if (i < 499 && i % 10 === 9) {
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 60000));
        }
    }
    return res.send(responses[0].status);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const maximum_tries_per_minute = 10;

const get_webpage = async (url) => {
    let re_tries = 0;
    while (re_tries < maximum_tries_per_minute) {
        await fetch(url);
        re_tries++;
    }
}

setInterval(get_webpage('https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limit-test'), 60000); // runs every minute
```